# Why did I get "The privacy policy URL you provided is invalid as it took so long to respond and directs to an error page. " for a working page?

Tags: actions-on-google

I submitted version 3 of my action on Google and was denied due to "Your Action's privacy policy is invalid." It says that the site took to long and directs to an error page. The link that I submitted is an active website. https://sc.gov/privacy-security-policy. What needs to be done to have this fixed?

Comment: "it took so long to respond and directs to an error page." is what happens when you go to your link. Maybe you have a firewall or something setup so it works for you but no one else?

Comment: Thanks. I'm verifying if that could be the cause of the problem now.

Comment: We do have a geo policy that restricts non-US ips. We would need the IP address that they are calling from to allow them access.

Comment: Your privacy policy should be publicly available, without any IP blocks, as it should be available not just to reviewers but to any user.

Answer (score 0):

Your privacy policy should be publicly available, without any IP blocks, as it should be available not just to reviewers but to any user.